# WSO2 ESB enrich mediator inside an iterator mediator

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I make a call to a DSS service and receive XML back I then use the iterator mediator to iterate over the  tag in the XML. Inside the iterator I use an enrich mediator to add some XML nodes to the XML but each time it loops or leaves the iterator the changes are gone, even on the last loop the returned XML does not keep any of the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate mediator acts like clone mediator. The difference is that it splits the initial message into several fragments (it does not duplicate the initial message)

If you choose to continue the parent mediation after iterate mediator (attribute continueParent set to true), you see the initial message (the one you were mediating before iterate occurs)

If you want to change the content of the initial message, you must use enrich / XSLT / javascript outside iterate or clone

Comment: Is there no way to copy values from inside the iterator to a property outside of it using an enrich mediator?

Comment: You work with a copy of the MessageContext (that holds the message payload, properties, ...) and can't access this copy in the parent mediation : why don't you consider an other way to apply your transformation ? what is the problem with XSLT or JavaScript ?

Comment: I've now solved this by placing an aggregater mediator after it Thanks for your help

Comment: @user3758298 could you elaborate on your aggregate solution?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I've been trying to use the iterator to change message payload structure for a while and I've found that it's just not what it's designed for.

The iterator is designed for cloning a message into smaller messages based on an XPATH expression. Within the target sequence you can do whatever you like with the message - which is usually calling another web service. But this message is more or less confined to the context of the iterator operation. Once the iterator finishes it's defined target sequence it'll scrap that message and if you've indicated you'd like to continue with the parent sequence after iteration has completed WSO2 will pick up the old message context by default.

### XSLT to the Rescue

I know what you're thinking - "god damn it, I have to learn something new". Which is why I've mostly ignored XSLT up until now - I figured I could do everything in the Synapse configuration language. But XSLT is seriously the bomb, I recommend checking out the tutorial up on W3Schools to see what you can do: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

The powerful thing about XSLT is that within a template you can use a for-each expression: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp

As arguments to that expression you can specify some XPATH (just like the iterate mediator), except that it will actually structure the message.

To use XSLT within the ESB, simply add a local XML entry with the XSLT stylesheet in it and reference the key in an XSLT mediator.